# Django: The included urlconf core.urls doesn't have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm having some weird issues with class-based-views and reverse_lazy.

Following error shows up when calling the website:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /dashboard/student/
The included urlconf core.urls doesn't have any patterns in it
```

My views.py:

```
class DashStudentMain(TemplateView):
    model_class = None
    template_name = 'learn/dashboard/snip_student_1.html'
    tab_list = {
        ("Main", reverse_lazy('dash_student_main_url')),
        #("History", reverse_lazy('dash_student_main_url'))
    }
    active_tab = "Main"
```

My core.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', 'core.views.home', name='home_url'),
    url(r'^home', 'core.views.home'),
    url(r'^dashboard/', include('tc_learn.dashboard.urls')),
    ...
)
```

My tc_learn.dashboard.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
from .views import DashStudentMain, DashStudentHistory

urlpatterns = patterns(
    # Student + Tabs
    url(r"^", DashStudentMain.as_view()),
    url(r"^student/$", DashStudentMain.as_view(), name="dash_student_main_url"),
    url(r"^student/history/$", DashStudentHistory.as_view(), name="dash_student_history_url"),
```

I've

- restarted the server, to make sure urls were loaded properly
- commented out **("Main", reverse_lazy('dash_student_main_url'))** to make sure that the urls.py syntax is fine
- deleted the line **url(r"^", DashStudentMain.as_view()),** since it's not used anyway, but without it /dashboard/student doesn't work at all..

Any idea what I might be missing? Thanks!

EDIT:
It looks like the issue is coming from the tab_list object.
When I directly assign the object via `tab_list = reverse_lazy('dash_student_main_url')`, the code works fine. When I use it inside a list, it's showing that error. Does anyone know of work-around for this scenario?

Comment: in your settings for `INSTALLED_APPS`, make sure `tc_learn` is _before_ `core`

Comment: Just tried that, but the error remains :/

Comment: This error normally occurs when it is trying to access urls from modules not loaded yet. So, you might want to resolve the order in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: @karthikr that's what the "lazy" part is for...

Comment: @Alvaro and it is evident that the "lazy" part is not being called somewhere

Comment: How about overriding get_context_data to generate tab_list instead? You can then have a list of urls that you can loop over in the template?

Comment: Check ROOT_URLCONF properly. There may be improperly configured ROOT_URLCONF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change this code:

```
tab_list = {
    ("Main", reverse_lazy('dash_student_main_url')),
    #("History", reverse_lazy('dash_student_main_url'))
}
```

to:

```
tab_list = [
    ("Main", reverse_lazy('dash_student_main_url')),
    #("History", reverse_lazy('dash_student_main_url'))
]
```

Contrary to a name you gave the variable, you were not creating a list, but a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set). Elements were evaluated immediately at the time of set creation, because sets need to know more about values they contain. Changing it to a proper list will allow the elements to be evaluated lazily, as intended.

Answer (score 2):

In tc_learn.dashboard.urls: you are missing the first argument (empty prefix in your case). Change it to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r"^", DashStudentMain.as_view()),
    url(r"^student/$", DashStudentMain.as_view(), name="dash_student_main_url"),
    url(r"^student/history/$", DashStudentHistory.as_view(), name="dash_student_history_url"),
)
```

Also, the first regex should be r"^$" if you want it to represent an empty one
And see if it works. Let me know!

Comment: That was fast! I just changed those lines and restarted the server, no luck either.

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'. Since everything works when I comment out "reverse_lazy", I'm not sure if it's a configuration issue

Comment: I see... sorry for not being helpful! I will try your code to see if I can figure out something !